# Add a tooltip for div in SVG (d3 v4)

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I want to add a tooltip when I hover the different colors in the below picture. The colors came from 2 `div`s that I set accordingly to what I want.

[Div image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Ro3E.png)

I have tried multiple things, but all didn't work out. Please help me.

Below is my code for the `div`s:

```
var rect  = g.append("rect")
             .attr("width", width-30)
             .attr("height", grpercent[i])
             .attr("x",xr)
             .attr("y",yr)
             .attr("fill", "yellow")
             .attr("class", "color")
             .on("mouseover", function(){
                 tooltip.transition()
                        .style("opacity", "1");

                 tooltip.html("Onboard: "+ grpercent[i])
                        .style("left", (d3.event.pageX)+"px")
                        .style("top", (d3.event.pageY)+"px");

                 d3.select(this).style("opacity", "0.5");
             })

             .on("mouseout", function(){
                 tooltip.transition()
                        .style("opacity", "0");

                 d3.select(this).style("opacity", "1");
             });
```

The tooltip code:

```
var tooltip = d3.select("body")
                .append("div")
                .style("position", "absolute")
                .style("background", "lightgray")
                .style("padding", " 10px")
                .style("border", "1px darkgrey solid")
                .style("border-radius", "2.5px")
                .style("opacity", "0");
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. 
What do you imply by "didn't work out"? Any error message? 
It would help if a stack snippet was created. Read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Does the body have `position:relative`? The parent element of one with `position:absolute` must have `position:relative`.